# Boot drive error

Tags: boot, usb

Now this error shows up

```
145.203138]SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x8fadff7e: -5
145.2038161
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block Oxa018b52c: -5
145.2050611
Buffer 1/0 error on dev 1oops,
logical block 242770, async page read
145.2050991
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x7d956465: -5
145.2058831
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x8226a721: -5
145.2064621
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0xb82ca85f: -5
145.207192
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x8fadff7e: -5
145.2077561
145.2091231
Buffer 1/0 error on dev 100p4,
logical block 75192, async page read
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x8226a721: -5
145.2091581
145.2105621
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read
block 0x7d956465: -5
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x8226a721: -5
153.5881701
suurshrs error: zilo decompression talled, data probably corrupt
153.5986931
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x3337088: -5
158.5400951
SQUASHFS error: 21ib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
153.5406631
153.8242381
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block 0x3337088: -5
1/0 error, dev loopo, sector 1854114 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
153.8250751
153.8259101
SQUASHFS
error: Failed to read block 0x3895450c: -5
I/0 error, dev loopo, sector 1854114 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 15 prio class 2
153.8266031
SQUASHFS
error: Failed to read block 0x3895450c: -5
153.873400]
SUUASHFS error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
153.873956]
SQUASHFS
error: Failed to read block 0x3337088: -5
153.8752851
SQUASHFS
error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
153.8757961
SQUASHFS
error: Failed to read block 0x3337088: -5
154.0415281
154.042363]
I/0 error, dev loopo, sector 1854114 op 0x0: (READ)
flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
SQUASHFS error:
Failed
to read block 0x3895450c: -5
154.0981731
SQUASHFS error:
zlib
154.093751]
decompression failed, data probably corrupt
SQUASHFS error:
Failed
to read block 0x3337088:
-5
154.0951011
SQUASHFS error:
154.0956071
SQUASHFS
154.2992821
1/0
error:
zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
Failed to read block 0x3337088:
-5
error,
dev
154.3000931
Loopo,
SQUASHFS error:
Failed
sector 1854114 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 2
154.3453471
to read block 0x3895450c: -5
SQUASHFS error:
154.3458931
Zlib decompression failed,
data probably corrupt
error:
Failed
154.3472761
SQUASHFS
to read block 0x3337088:
SQUASHFS error:
Z1ib
154.3477971
SQUASHFS
decompression failed, data probably corrupt
154.5416731
1/0
error: Failed to read block 0x3337088:
error,
154.
542228]
dev loopo,
sector
1854114 op 0x0: (READ)
SQUASHFS error:
154.5864811
SQUASHFS error:
Failed to read block 0x3895450c: -5
flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
Zlib
154.5871331
SQUASHFS
decompression failed, data probably corrupt
154.5888371
error: Failed to read block 0x3337088:
SQUASHFS
154.5894621
SQUASHFS
error: zlib decompression failed, error:
154.8031391
1/0 error,
Failed to read block 0x3337088: -5
data probably corrupt
154.8037461
dev loopo,
SQUASHFS
sector 1854114 op
154.9736051
I/0 error,
Failed to read block 0x3895450c: -5
Oxo: (READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
dev loopo,
154.9747001
SQUASHFS
sector 1829794 op
154.9756731
error: Failed to read block
0x37d7456a:
0X0: (READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 7 prio class 2
1/0 error,
154.976590]
dev loopo, sector 1829794 op
SQUASHFS error: Failed to read block
0x37d7456a:
0x0: (READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 7 prio
```

Comment: corrupt install medium?

Comment: You've provided no clear specifics; but *squashfs* errors tell you a squashed file-system is corrupt; which is often seen prior to install because ISO was faulty, or it wasn't written correctly to thumb-drive etc.. The media checks (*if performed*) will reveal this but you gave no specifics as to your product/release or what checks you performed. After install you're prompted to remove media & press ENTER to reboot; these errors can re-occur after media is removed & in that circumstance you can ignored them (*they're expected when you remove media*) but you gave no clear details.

Comment: You need to evaluate your OS/release details, product & ISO, and what you were doing BEFORE those messages occurred to fully understand it; as we're limited to what you provide - we can only *speculate* as to the actual cause.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this and have no idea what to do any more because I tried everything ppl told me